# Display hidden form field based on select box choice

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is a form element I have.

```
<select id="state" name="state" style="width: 212px;">
<option value="nsw">New South Wales</option>
<option value="qld">Queensland</option>
<option value="vic">Victoria</option>
<option value="nt">Northern Territory</option>
<option value="tas">Tasmania</option>
<option value="sa">South Australia</option>
<option value="wa">Western Australia</option>
<option value="act">Australian Capital Territory</option>
<option value="notinoz">Not in Australia</option>
 </select>
```

What I want to do is below this add another select box element , if user chooses "not in Australia" in the options above.
I am really after the cleanest lightest code possbile.

I am presuming we create a div and set visibility:hidden just not sure how to trigger it.

Comment: You don't need a hidden _div_, you can have a hidden _select_. Although I guess you probably also want a label and so forth. You may want to think about `display:none` rather than `visibility:hidden`, but that's up to you. You need to handle the change event on your "state" select element, and then hide or show the next select element by changing its `visibility` (or `display`).(By the way, why is the ACT last? We should be _first_...)

Comment: lol @nnnnnn I was gonna try and trigger display:none to display:block just not sure how to do it using js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#state").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() != "notinoz") {
                    $("#foo").show();
                }else{
                    $("#foo").hide();
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>


<body>
    <p>
        <select id="state" name="state" style="width: 212px;">
            <option value="nsw">New South Wales</option>
            <option value="qld">Queensland</option>
            <option value="vic">Victoria</option>
            <option value="nt">Northern Territory</option>
            <option value="tas">Tasmania</option>
            <option value="sa">South Australia</option>
            <option value="wa">Western Australia</option>
            <option value="act">Australian Capital Territory</option>
            <option value="notinoz">Not in Australia</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p id="foo" style="display:none;">
        <select style="width: 212px;>
            <option value="item1">Item</option>
            <option value="item2">Item</option>
            <option value="item3">Item</option>
        </select>
    </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Excellent, I actually add 'fast' to elements and reveresed hide and show thankyou

Comment: This involves jQuery, a little overkill for this task.

Answer (score 6):

How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/JKqWf/4/

HTML

```
<select id="state" name="state" style="width: 212px;" onclick='test()'>
<option value="nsw">New South Wales</option>
<option value="qld">Queensland</option>
<option value="vic">Victoria</option>
<option value="nt">Northern Territory</option>
<option value="tas">Tasmania</option>
<option value="sa">South Australia</option>
<option value="wa">Western Australia</option>
<option value="act">Australian Capital Territory</option>
<option value="notinoz">Not in Australia</option>
 </select>

<select id="extra" name="extra" style="display: none">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function test() {
    if (document.getElementById('state').value == 'notinoz') {
        document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do select elements normally have 'block' display? Might want to set `.display = '';` which effectively removes the inline style and lets the defaults (from the relevant style cascade) take effect.

Comment: Not sure if the OP will actually use inline styling but here's another option `document.getElementById('extra').removeAttribute('style')`.