# php - Get hidden form field Value based on select box choice

Tags: php

Sorry for my bad title!:)
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812397/display-hidden-form-field-based-on-select-box-choice) how can I check and store the appeared field's value With php and mysql;

assume that the form is something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <select name="job" id="job" class="medium">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="1">Job A</option>
        <option value="2">Job B</option>
        <option value="3">Job C</option>
        <option value="4">Job D</option>
        <option value="0">Other</option>
    </select>

    <div id="foo" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="job_other" id="job_other" placeholder="If Other, please specify" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

when selecting the "Other" option, "job_other" text field will appear.(handled by javascript)
is my procedure true to check and get field in php like this:

```
<?php 
 $input['job'] = (isset($_POST['job']) && $_POST['job'] != '-1') ? $_POST['job'] : '';

 if ( $input['job'] != '' &&  $input['job'] == '0') {
    $input['job_other'] = (isset($_POST['job_other']) && $_POST['job_other'] != '' && $_POST['job_other'] == '0') ? $_POST['job_other'] : '';
 }

?>
```

By the way when the field appear, it will be Required.
so how can I do this better?

Comment: `if ( $input['job'] != '' &&  $input['job'] == '0')` could be simplified by `if($input['job'] == '0')` : [demo](http://codepad.org/ZMGYDSUi)

Comment: Question title is fine but question contents I couldn't understand, could you please rephrase what you want?

Comment: thank you! I didn't know that can simplify it like this.

Comment: I want to get the hidden field just when it appears in the form as a required field by php.

Comment: Oops, actually I messed up... You should test like so : `if($input['job'] === '0')` so it doesn't match `false`, `0` or `FALSE`. [Demo](http://codepad.org/k3D79XJ5)

Comment: you mean just use `if($input['job'] === '0')`. am I right?

Comment: You should use jquery form plugin, and all validation and if-else stuffs do with javascript, and after all that just make an ajax request with parameters. It's more better to do that in this way. On this link you have jquery form plugin
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: "[...] is my procedure true to check and get field in php like this:", this was meant to be the question? What errors you got? What have you tried? Is this code working?

Comment: @Rafael Barros - it works fine but there are so many field in my real form, and if I check for each of them code will be like an spaghetti.

Comment: @Brewal - TNX a lot dear friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be sufficient:

```
<?php 
 $input['job'] = (isset($_POST['job'])) ? (int) $_POST['job'] : -1;

 $input['job_other'] = ( ($input['job'] == 0) && (isset($_POST['job_other'])) ) ? $_POST['job_other'] : '';
?>
```

Save the 'job' field as *integer* and 'job_other' as *string / varchar*.

Comment: what if user dont select "other" option? again I store the field as an  empty string? `<?php 
 $input['job'] = (isset($_POST['job'])) ? (int) $_POST['job'] : -1;

 if ( $input['job'] == 0) {
    $input['job_other'] = (isset($_POST['job_other'])) ? $_POST['job_other'] : '';
 } else {$input['job_other'] = '';}
?>`

Comment: Yes, or use the revised solution :)